# SQL Server : Select max with Sub-select

Tags: sql-server, select, max, subquery

I am try to get a max value of a result set of another select in SQL Server, but not able to.  I am not sure what I am doing incorrect in SQL Server. Any help would be great.

This is my SQL:

```
select 
    max(A.ID), A.Name, A.RMName, A.RName, A.DName, A.Section, A.CF, A.PPV, A.ESD,
    A.EED, A.EJ, 
    A.NJ, A.NAF, A.L4MAF, A.L4MJ, A.MLF, A.PL, A.PN, A.EMSFL, A.PV, A.FName, 
    A.FLevel, A.SC, A.PID, A.PFID 
from (
        select distinct 
            ID, Name, RMName, RName, DName, Section, CF, PPV,
            REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR, ESD, 6), ' ', '-') ESD,
            REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR, EED, 6), ' ', '-') EED,
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(EJ, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '') as EJ,
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(NJ,CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '') as NJ,
            NAF,
            L4MAF,
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(L4MJ,CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '') as L4MJ,
            MLF,
            PL,
            PN,
            EMSFL,
            PV,
            FName,
            FLevel,
            SC,
            PID,
            PFID
        from 
            dbo.DFD def (nolock),
            dbo.DForm form (nolock),
            dbo.DExcp exc (nolock)
        where 
            exc.DPID = def.DFDID
            and def.DFID = form.DFID
            and NAF = 1
            and L4MAF = 1
            and RMName is not null
            and EED >= GETDATE()
            and EED <> '2050-01-01 00:00:00.000') as A
group by 
     Name, RMName, RName, DName, Section, CF, 
     PPV, ESD, EED, EJ, NJ, NAF, L4MAF, L4MJ, 
     MLF, PL, PN, EMSFL, PV, FName, FLevel, 
     SC, PID, PFID
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you attempting to get the values for all the columns of the row in a subquery whose ID is the Maximum value?

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm not able to"?. Do you get an error?, wrong results?

Comment: Yes, I need to display all returned values from all rows and based on the result set I need to display one max ID as all the rest of the fields may have same data in all other rows.

Comment: I am not able to get max ID of the result set which is being return and number of records are same or not giving me the max of column ID.

Comment: You are far more likely to get help if you simplify your query down to a minimal example that demonstrates your problem, and give actual vs expected results.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I thought to show what I am doing and what I am trying to achieve.  Maybe I can get a example help with simple generic sql.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is somewhat unclear. I'll give you a an example based on what I think you're asking

Get all Rows that have Id = to Max Id

```
SELECT
   b.*
FROM
   (SELECT MAX(Id) AS [MaxId] From MyTable) a INNER JOIN
   MyTable b ON a.MaxId = b.Id
```

There are other ways to do this but this will give you all rows in your table that have an Id equal to the maximum id in your table. I can tailor a more specific example if I have misunderstood what you're getting at.

-Ben